Plagiarism in paragraph and image, or not?
I wrote a review paper with my classmate during our master's program. We checked it in Turnitin, and the similarity was less than 10%. It got published in an Elsevier journal with an impact factor of 5.
After a year, I was reading an old paper by "X" on a similar topic and found three paragraphs to be very similar to our paper. When I asked about it, my friend told me that he had initially taken those three paragraphs from this paper, rephrased them in his own words (no similarity detected in Turnitin), and cited the main paper at the end of the paragraphs while giving secondary citations in the main paragraph lines. He says that he checked each paper himself for the claims made in "X" person's paper.
From the same paper, there was an image that he used as a basis to create a similar kind of image for our paper. Although the images don't resemble each other in style and the content is also changed a bit, the original paper was not cited in the image title.
Is this plagiarism or ethical? And if it is then any suggestions you want to share?

The image - was it some kind of diagram, or some sort of graph of data?

Too little information about the image to judge whether this is an instance of plagiarism or not. "Used as a basis" can mean many things.

@MikeB It was a diagram.

@AdamPřenosil Original diagram was depicting a complex pathway interlinking multiple metabolisms, the adapted diagram only depicted a particular metabolic pathway out of the original, and he added one-two new labels in the diagram.

@Akash Cropping out a part of someone else's diagram without attribution sounds like a pretty clear cut case of plagiarism to me.

As someone who's dealt with scores of academic plagiarism cases, the following is a red flag, common to how offenders usually describe their work:

found three paragraphs to be very similar to our paper... he had
initially taken those three paragraphs from this paper, rephrased them
in his own words...

My judgement would be that yes, this is plagiarism. If one can identify on sight that three paragraphs from your paper are parallel to three paragraphs from a prior paper, that's too similar. Starting off by copying someone else's words and then adjusting it to avoid plagiarism-detection is plagiarism; as one example among many, the IEEE says:

... we should be able to agree that changing only a few words or
phrases or only rearranging the original sentence order of another
author's work will be defined as plagiarism.

For more discussion, see: Is changing some words plagiarism?

The image used might be more difficult to judge. Does it contain ideas independent of the text that was cited? Was it just used as "inspiration" for a style? Copying an image directly can be copyright infringement. I don't see enough information here to judge whether the image is plagiarism or not. If it attributes ideas of others to yourself it would be, but it isn't clear that this happened.

Why do you think it is plagiarism if they cited the original following the paraphrase? That seems to be proper attribution of the ideas. Paraphrasing is often necessary to avoid copyright infringement when it takes many words to express the ideas. Over quoting is copyright infringement.

@Buffy If they had just directly quoted some of the material and provided proper attribution, I do not think that there would be any issue at all.  However, the action of subtly changing the text in order to avoid setting off a similarity detector like Turnitin suggests a mens rea, which makes me less comfortable with the situation.  It feels like there is an intent to deceive, which is very much at the heart of what plagiarism is.

@XanderHenderson The poster doesn't actually say that the partner changed the text in order to avoid detection by Turnitin, just that Turnitin didn't detect plagiarism after the fact. Also, plagiarism doesn't require a mens rea in order to be plagiarism; people plagiarize accidentally all the time. Plagiarism just requires that one use someone else's work and pass it off as their own. This sounds like fairly normal paraphrasing, with attribution to the original author, albeit a longer chunk of text than usual.

The image is a lot more questionable, I think, given that it sounds like the partner "paraphrased" it as well, without attribution.

@WhatTheDuck Sure, plagiarism does not require mens rea.  But that is the converse of what I said, and is not logically equivalent.  My claim is that if there is an intent to deceive, then the actions are more likely to cross the line into plagiarism.  As to whether or not there is an intention to deceive, we are looking at a second-hand account of the situation (i.e. the asker reporting what their collaborator said).  It is very hard to understand what is happening in this situation.

@WhatTheDuck My feeling is that if the OP can tell that his co-author had based their paragraphs on the other paper, several years later, then they are too close. It suggests that is more "theasurused" than it is "paraphrased". An attribution would usually be take as crediting the ideas to someone else, but it looks like here, its not just the idea that has been taken from elsewere, but also how to express the idea.

@Buffy Even with citations, insufficient/improper/inadequate paraphrasing is still considered plagiarism. Based on OP's description (three paragraphs similar enough for OP to recognize them), that seems to be possible evidence for improper paraphrasing. Proper paraphrasing would probably have better integration with the rest of the work and show originality with the use of the ideas from the source paragraphs

Why are so many people in the comments assuming insufficient rephrasing? What I read in the OP could very well describe "I read the paper, and then wrote my own text describing the information given in those three paragraphs". As Buffy said, this is entirely normal and perfectly fine as long as the source is cited.

Daniel, you left out the "and cited the main paper at the end of the paragraphs while giving secondary citations in the main paragraph lines" bit that appears right after the first clause you quoted. That part rather changes the situation. (It's still possible that the citations were placed in a location that makes it unclear what bits they apply to, but rephrasing and citing doesn't suggest a mens rea, whereas rephrasing just enough to avoid turnitin certainly would.)

@terdon I think 1) because OP spotted the similarity a year later, and 2) because three paragraphs is a long passage to paraphrase. If someone has turned three paragraphs into three paragraphs with different phrasing but the same information, it's almost certain that they've failed to paraphrase appropriately.

@anjama and others. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism. Understand the elements of plagiarism. In particular look at Teddi Fishman's definition.

@Buffy You're using an extremely narrow view of plagiarism where it seems you find that any attribution of the source is sufficient to make it "not plagiarism". I think you are very wrong about this, it does not follow typical standards used within academia, and worry that you are misleading others by your insistence. A mere citation does not acknowledge that one has taken entirely the structure and expression of an idea, the way to do that is to use quotation marks and to use the expression identically, rather than to pretend one is not doing so by merely substituting some words.

@Buffy I'm not clear that what I said conflicts with Fishman's definition. Even if it does, the very last line of Fishman's paper clearly states the proposed definition was intended as a starting point for future discussion and revisions. Additionally, the Yale definition on Wikipedia right after Fishman's definition states what I said (their website even has examples), as does the survey in the next Wikipedia section identifying the 10 main forms of plagiarism.

Gutsy call coming right out and calling it plagiarism without seeing either version.

Maybe, I've misunderstood our guidelines, maybe stuff works different here in Germany. (I think it might a bit different, as "fair use" doesn't exist here)
When writing a paper for university, we were told to avoid verbatim copies for the sake of copyright (not for "academic correctness") and provide sources for each claim made (for "academic correctness").
Unless, they were actual quotes, rephrasing the content in a way relevant to our context and adding attributions, was what we should do.
In fact, it was actively encouraged to have as many sources as possible and avoid "second-hand" sources.
This ESPECIALLY included redrawing graphics, adjusting them to our paper and adding sources. If the original graphic was relevant enough already and we had permission of the original author, we could copy&paste the graphic with proper attribution.
So, your second paragraph, given that proper attribution took place, seems completely fine to me.
I see an issue with the latter (the redrawn graphic), which insinuates, that no proper attribution has been made.
Plagiarism exclusively refers to taking someone else's work and disguising it as your own. Straight-up copying someone else's work, but giving proper attribution, is a copyright violation and lazy and would be graded accordingly, but would not be plagiarism, from my understanding.

Yes!. This answer correctly distinguishes between copyright and plagiarism. Over quoting can be a copyright violation, even with citation. Citation avoids plagiarism, even with paraphrasing.

@Buffy Citation does not automatically change the nature of something from "plagiarism" to "not plagiarism".  The core of plagiarism is passing off another's work as your own.  It is not hard to directly copy someone else's work, then selectively edit it to obfuscate which parts of the text are the original author's ideas.  Moreover, if a significant portion of your paper is paraphrasings of other people's work, it is likely to run afoul of plagiarism, citations or not.

@XanderHenderson we are talking about three paragraphs here; can't really be "a significant portion" of the work. We all read papers, learn from them, and then reproduce that knowledge in our own words while citing the original authors. I don't see any reason to assume the OP went much further than that. Especially if the text was changed enough to satisfy Turnitin. It sounds to me (I may be wrong, of course, we don't have a clear picture here) that the OP just wrote three paragraphs making the same points in the same order as the original—cited—paper, but using their own words.

@terdon I've said very little about this particular situation---I've only responded to the general idea that "citation abrogates plagiarism".  In a general sense, simply adding a citation to text which would otherwise be considered plagiarism does not automatically make it not-plagiarism.  At an extreme, there is the patchwork paper, where every paragraph is essentially a paraphrase of a different author (i.e. a significant portion of the paper is paraphrased).  This particular case seems to fall nearer to the opposite extreme, but that wasn't what I was responding to.

So plagiarism is usually formally defined as passing off someone else's ideas, words, or work as your own, without proper attribution. By that very straightforward definition, on the surface this isn't plagiarism, since the ideas were cited and the words were your classmates own. I think this is a trap that many students fall into.
But (and this is a big but) usually when we talk about plagiarism in academic writing, it includes paraphrasing and other less obvious actions even if you then cite the original author. For instance, I cannot (or should not) just lift entire sections from another's work, rewrite it, cite it, and then pass it off as my own. I always reasoned that you were essentially using their work (as opposed to ideas or written words) without proper attribution. Unless you clearly mark something with quotations or make some statement to the effect of "this has been adapted from X" you are not giving proper credit.
Unfortunately, this is almost impossible to catch using traditional plagiarism methods - tools like turnitin are essentially only good for catching direct word-for-word repetitions. They are very easy to circumvent and yet are still prone to false positives. On top of that, I don't think it's a very intuitive definition. It takes some experience to delineate inappropriate paraphrasing from synthesis even for well intentioned writers.
It doesn't help that there are legitimate shades of grey to this. Sometimes there are really only so many ways to state certain facts or certain results. I think a lot of students struggle with making this distinction though. I won't speculate about your paper in particular, but it doesn't sound like this is the case.
That's all to say, this was not ethical and falls somewhere on the spectrum of plagiarism. Whether or not it was intentional I think makes some difference, since I would argue that intentionally changing words to circumvent a plagiarism detector is absolutely plagiarism. However, I have encountered plenty of well intentioned students that just don't make this connection and think that by paraphrasing they are doing the right thing.

Why do you think they are "passing it off as their own"? A citation points to the source of the ideas. Paraphrasing doesn't require quotes and they would be wrong in any case. Paraphrasing with citation is NOT plagiarism.

@Buffy It depends; paraphrasing too closely can also be considered plagiarism. A citation suggests you've merely taken meaning, but it's possible to also copy the structure and pattern of the writing by just using synonyms and changes to sentence structure. For something as short of a sentence, that's okay, but for longer writing it's much better to just admit you're quoting the original and quote it.

@BryanKrause, please stop deleting my comments.

Some examples: https://law-richmond.libguides.com/c.php?g=998384&p=7227189 https://www.utc.edu/library/help/tutorials/plagiarism/examples-of-plagiarism https://integrity.mit.edu/handbook/academic-writing/avoiding-plagiarism-paraphrasing

@BryanKrause, you seem to be suggesting copyright infringement as a guard against plagiarism. It is citation, actually, that is the guard.

@Buffy I don't know where you're getting that impression. You're the only one talking about copyright.

@BryanKrause I think the MIT reference there is one of the best explainations we've seen, and we use a very similar set of examples with our undergraduates.

@Buffy I disagree, a citation alone does not stop plagiarism in its tracks. Paraphrasing, even with a citation, can still be plagiarism. Per the OP, their coauthor lifted several entire paragraphs from another's work. The changes that they made were apparently small enough that the section was immediately recognizable in it's original form - it appears even the citations were left unchanged. Paraphrasing should capture the original meaning, not the original structure and form.

Citation does not exclude plagiarism
There are several possible reasons to cite existing work, including
(non-exhaustively):

Indicate topical relevance.

Acknowledge discovery priority.

Import that work's claim to support a broader argument.

Use the work as additional evidence for your own claim.

Present the work's claim as an object of study.  (For example, "X
says Y but we think ... .")


Plagiarism is the misrepresentation of someone else's work as your own.
Just because a sentence or paragraph ends with a citation of the work it
is based on does not automatically mean it can't be plagiarism.  You
must ask yourself:

Would a reasonable reader, who has not read the cited work, think the
material in question is original to the author?

In asking this, you must consider the multiple possible reasons for a
citation and which one the reader is likely to assume.  If a reasonable
reader would conclude the material is original, but it is not, then that
is plagiarism.
If your intent is to cite for purpose 3, claim importation, then you
must either quote, or else paraphrase while saying you are
paraphrasing (and of course cite in both cases).  You might also
summarize and say you are summarizing.
If your intent is to cite for purpose 4, claim support, then the claim
must be your own independent formulation.
The question states:

he had initially taken those three paragraphs from this paper,
rephrased them in his own words (no similarity detected in Turnitin),
and cited the main paper at the end of the paragraphs

I judge this to be plagiarism.  It deliberately looks like purpose 4,
mere claim support, but is really (at best) purpose 3, claim
importation.
The citation mitigates the severity of the offense only.
Figures and images can be "paraphrased"
If I see someone's image and then create something based on it,
presumably with similar organization, choice of what data to include,
perhaps choice of graph axes, etc., then I'm doing something like
paraphrasing but for an image.  (I'm not sure what the right term is
for this.  It is related to the legal notion of a derivative work but
this question is mainly about ethics and academic integrity.)
As with text, if a reasonable reader would conclude that the image is
entirely the original work of the author, but is in fact based on
someone else's image, then that is plagiarism.
The question states:

there was an image that he used as a basis to create a similar kind of
image for our paper. Although the images don't resemble each other in
style and the content is also changed a bit

From "used as a basis" and "content is also changed a bit", I think
it is clear that this image was not the original work of the author.
Therefore that fact must be made clear to the reader.  Failure to do so
is plagiarism, regardless of where the citations are.
What now?
At the end of the question, it asks:

And if it is then any suggestions you want to share?

Although I do think this is plagiarism, it is toward the milder end of
the spectrum.  As a co-author, I probably wouldn't try to do anything
about the already published paper in this instance, but I would try to
talk to with a trusted advisor to double-check that decision.  This
could come back to bite you in the future, particularly if you think
you'll apply for a faculty job at some point.
But:

Make it clear to your co-author that this is plagiarism, and that by
doing so they have jeopardized both their and your careers.  Three
paragraphs and an image is not insubstantial.

Be careful about working with people who have shown lack of concern
for academic integrity.  Be particularly wary of those who offer
excuses about deadlines or whatnot, as that is advance cover for a
repeat offense.

Try to read, or at very least skim, all of the papers your paper
cites, even if you did not add the citation.  You would likely have
caught this before publication if you had, especially the similar
image.

Going forward, resolve to always strive to be clear with your readers
when material is not entirely original.  There is nothing wrong with
using and building upon others' work so long as there is clear, proper
attribution.


Related
The question
Is paraphrasing with citation considered plagiarism?
makes similar points but the facts there are a little different and do
not include the image aspect.
The question
I found out that I have plagiarism in my published journal papers, what should I do now?
has some ideas that may or may not be applicable.
The University of Virginia article
Understanding Citations, Plagiarism, and Paraphrasing
states:

[...] even where you have cited the original author, you may, in the
manner and extent to which you go on to convey the author's ideas, be
found to have represented that author's ideas or work as your own.

although they then give a more obvious example than in this question.
Regarding possible future repercussions, the article
Plagiarism Among Applicants for Faculty Positions
by Harirforoosh et al. says:

As such, it is essential to check all application materials submitted
by faculty applicants for any evidence of plagiarism.

Now, they are primarily talking about the application itself (like
the statement of purpose, etc.) rather than digging through past
publications, but the latter is not inconceivable.

It might be unethical but it is not plagiarism.
Plagiarism is falsely representing an idea as your own. Since he was an originator of the idea in previous work, this is not plagiarism. There is some question in this case whether he his pretending to be a sole originator as opposed to a co-originator, so it might fall into a boundary. However, plagiarism may be the highest academic crime and to accuse someone of plagiarism for reusing their ideas is probably going to far, even when they're not giving all due parties credit.
However, citation and credit are important for many reasons: Novel research is more important than other research. All the originators of an idea deserve credit for their work, including coauthors. Journals deserve to be recognized for publishing important work. Others deserve to know the accurate history and development of an idea. And so on. When a citation trail is incomplete, inaccurate, or missing, these important features of good academic work are incomplete.
This case sound in particular like it might give a false appearance of novelty.
The norms of citation are clear: you should cite conceptually prior work that you are aware of, even if you are extending or elaborating on the ideas. Knowingly not citing prior work for any reason is unethical. This person clearly knows of the prior work and even consulted it in the production of the present one. Unethical is a matter of degree and many specifics are missing to judge whether this is seriously unethical.

"Since he was an originator of the idea in previous work"  - I don't see this mentioned anywhere in the question.
